# Insert UITabBarItem at Specific Index

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

My **Swift 4** `UITabBarController` usually has *four* `UITabBarItem` items on it.
In certain circumstances it can have *five* instead of four, but I always want the far right button to be the same. That means I need to dynamically insert and/or remove the `UITabBarItem` in the fourth "slot".

I'm able to handle adding and removing the `UITabBarItem` in code with no problem, but I haven't been able to determine how to do it other than by using `.append`, which only will add it to the fifth "slot".

Hours of poring over the Apple documentation and Stack Overflow have yielded no solution. How can I insert a `UITabBarItem` at a specific index?

Comment: using Storyboard or Adding it programatically ?

Comment: `myTBC.viewControllers?.insert(vc5, at: 3)` and `myTBC.viewControllers?.remove(at: 3)`

Comment: @vacawama Great Scott! That was exactly what I needed. Can I ask where you found that? And can you please post that as an answer instead of a comment so I can flag it as the accepted answer?  THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` has a property called `viewControllers` which is the array of viewControllers that it manages.

If you want to insert a new viewController (let's call it `vc5`) at slot `4`, then you need to insert it into that array at index `3` since the counting starts at `0`:

```
myTBC.viewControllers?.insert(vc5, at: 3)
```

Likewise, to remove a viewController from the 4th slot:

```
myTBC.viewControllers?.remove(at: 3)
```

You can read more about working with `UITabBarController` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller).  Also check out Array mutating functions [`insert(_:at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641389-insert) and [`remove(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641390-remove).